# Dart make custom HttpRequest

Tags: flutter, api, http, dart, testing

I want to make a custom HttpRequest to unit test my api code.
The code I want to test:

```
if (WebSocketTransformer.isUpgradeRequest(request)) {
      await webSocketRequest.handleRequest(
          request: request, streamController: streamController);
}
```

The method `WebSocketTransformer` checks the method and the headers content. Therefore I have to hand in a `HttpRequest`.

```
  HttpRequest mockWSRequest; 
  mockWSrequest.headers.set('connection', 'upgrade');
```

But how can I set the `HttpRequest`'s method?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about `dart:io`'s `HttpRequest` class, that class is `abstract` and cannot be directly instantiated.  If you want to create a mock, then you would have your mock implement the `HttpRequest` interface and add an implementation for its [`method` getter](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-io/HttpRequest/method.html) to return `'GET'` or `'POST'` as desired.